# hiutil not indexing properly in Mountain Lion?

Tags: html, macos

I use Voodoopad to create my help docs, as described [here](http://developer.casgrain.com/?p=16).  Basically I have a Run Script build phase which tells Voodoopad to export my document as html.  The Voodoopad doc is set to run hiutil to create the help index when it exports.

After noticing that many of my help anchors weren't working, I traced it back to hiutil.  When I run hiutil on the html exported from Voodoopad, I get a bunch of errors:

```
Zach-iMac:Desktop zach$ hiutil -a --create Help/ --file Help/Help.helpindex -1 -vvv
index.html -- Parse error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 76.)
index.html -- Parse error: Error 76, Description: (null), Line: 14, Column: 8
index.html -- Finished parsing
```

These errors are repeated for every single file.  Line 14, column 8 is the closing of the head tag.  The first part of every file is basically the same:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<meta name="AppleTitle" content="VideoBuffet Help">
<meta name="AppleIcon" content="appicon16.png">
<title>Index</title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
<meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1138.23">
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 12.0px 'Lucida Grande'}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

This exact HTML used to work just fine with hiutil.  Since the last time I've run this I upgraded to Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.5.

Is anyone else using hiutil, and is it working for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use this prologue at the top of your HTML file:

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

and run your HTML through a validator like http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_upload+with_options

and fix all the problems until the validator returns success, it should work with hiutil 1.3. It did for me anyway.

See also http://lists.apple.com/archives/apple-help-authoring/2012/Sep/msg00018.html

Comment: Yep, I see now that the markup exported from Voodoopad wasn't valid. Changing the doctype to XHML 1.0 as you said, and fixing up a few errors in the exported markup did the trick. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

It's not a proper answer, but my workaround is to use the version of hiutil that shipped with Lion (1.2) to build my help index.

I'm not very happy with this, but it will do for now.  If anyone has this issue, and wants to learn how to do it, you can [read my blog post about it](http://zpasternack.blogspot.com/2012/09/working-around-broken-hiutil-in.html).

Update: posted [rdar://12326432](http://openradar.appspot.com/12326432)

Update: I've heard from Apple this is a duplicate of bug #11981648 (which is still open at this moment).